# Is there an API call to get a list of saved places in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a ton of saved places that appear on my Google Maps - but there is no way to manage, filter or search them. Is there a way to access these locations by API?

I scanned the maps api and can't find any reference. Is there another Google API that makes this available?

Comment: Where are they saved places located? Google Account? Database?

Comment: Yes, these are the places you save by hitting the star

Comment: just for reference, you can access all the saved list [here](https://www.google.com/save). So maybe a web crawler like [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can help?

Answer (score 10):

There do have a REST API can retrieve the saved places.

http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml

Visit this link to get more information.
https://www.google.com/bookmarks/

There are also api like:

https://www.google.com/bookmarks/find?q=conf&output=xml&num=10000
https://www.google.com/bookmarks/lookup?

But seems like they have been deprecated and most of document are not available anymore. Use them as you own risk.

Comment: This was helpful. For each bookmark there is a title, url, timestamp, and id field. I would like to get the actual location coordinates for each bookmark. Do you know of a way do this? I assume there must be a way to get them using the url...

Comment: If you are looking for google map url then you can check google's document. Try this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Comment: Wow, looks interesting, and while this is at least *something*, you're merely getting a list of your "starred" places. This won't get you a requested places list in a controllable way. Plus the URL looks suspicious: `/bookmarks` is too general and not one bit like a proper API endpoint. This feels like some XML export tool leftover from 2007, and may very well be deprecated sooner rather than later.

Comment: @River2202 These links no longer work as of 2023.

Answer (score 8):

Currently the list of saved places in My Maps is not available via an API.  There is a feature request tracking this you can use to follow along @ https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953.

Answer (score 6):

**2022:** I created a gist for parsing saved places from a shared list via python. It is really unstable because its a quick&dirty solution but maybe it will help someone: https://gist.github.com/ByteSizedMarius/8c9df821ebb69b07f2d82de01e68387d

Edit: The above answer did not yet take pagination into consideration. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964713/obtain-list-of-my-places-from-google-maps/73085314#73085314).